# MD5 + Salt giving me some strange characters

Tags: php, mysql, security

```
$salt = uniqid();
   $crypt = md5($password , $salt);
   $new_pass = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

In the database: `­ot÷„[ªà%ÛÅ‰¹:17b8bc731c322c9e05a26666458117f4`

Is this a syntactical error? Or is the database not set up with the correct character formatting?

Comment: So, 12 bytes for the MD5 digest and 32 characters for the `uniqid` output? Weird...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You enabled `raw_output`

[PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

> If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the md5 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 16.

Change

```
$crypt = md5($password , $salt);
                       ^------ You moved the salt to raw_output
```

To

```
$crypt = md5($password . $salt);
                       ^------ Should be this
```

For security reasons i would not advice you to use `md5` for password hashing. MD5 is so badly broken that it no longer takes so long to find an appropriate collision or reverse hash. **Once broken, a hash algorithm only gets worse**, never better therefore it would be better to choose an unbroken hash algorithm.

Standard

- [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)
- [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) (sha256 & sha512)

Better Alternatives

- [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)
- [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [PBKDF2](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard)

Comment: Did you mean "note" instead of "not"?